# Why android:exported is false in the Service used to receive Firebase push notification?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Based on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element

Regarding the meaning of `android:exported`

> Whether or not components of other applications can invoke the service
> or interact with it — "true" if they can, and "false" if not. When the
> value is "false", only components of the same application or
> applications with the same user ID can start the service or bind to
> it.

When I look at the code https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

```
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I thought when we are receiving push notification, it is the **external Android system** (considered as "other app") which invokes our app code. If that is so, why `android:exported` is false in the above case?

Isn't it should be true, if it is an external app which invokes our app code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go to check Android Manifest of firebase-message, you can find `FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver` is the actual `Service` used to receive message.

[image]

Also check out this PR https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/pull/850:

> Set FirebaseMessagingServices to exported="false" to explicitly
> prevent other apps from being able to send messages to it.

Answer (score 2):

to be exact: afaik Google Play Services app is distributing pushes ("other app"). so yes, this `Service` should be `exported` if it is a receiver. BUT are you shure that this developer-side declared `Service` is obtaining push data directly from some external source/app? I bet "real receiver" of push messages is declared internally in Firebase library, is `exported` and does some hard job preventing injections + reading some additional metadata etc. And at the end it sends push data to developer-declared `Service`, which works in same process/app, thus this may not be `exported` (probably even shouldn't for safety purposes)

just guessing, but it looks like Google-style, and also reasonable, approach. don't have access to sources ;) maybe check out Merged manifest in Android Studio, it will show ALL declared activities, services, broadcasts, permissions etc. - sum of your entries and all imported libs (well, "merged")